# Magento - Showing simple product in mail

Tags: image, magento, product

My issue is that I would like to show the image of a simple product in the order/invoice transactional email, but what is happening is that the image set for the configurable product image is what shows up.

For example, I have a T-Shirt configurable product made up of black shirt, blue shirt and grey handbag. The image for the configurable product is the grey shirt. When the user orders the blue shirt or black shirt the image is always the grey shirt.

Here's the code I use in email/order/items/order/default.html

```
<p align="center"><img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail')->resize(125); ?>" width="125" height="125" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" /></p>
```

Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution (maybe one of many but it works):

```
> <img src="<?php echo
> Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$_item->getSku())->getSmallImageUrl();
> ?>" width="125" height="125" alt="<?php echo
> $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" /></p>
```

You first get the SKU of the Item and load the simple product by searching for the sku. Afterwards you can get the thumbnail or small image.... It worked!